# How do you restart Ruby on Rails on Windows IIS 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you restart Ruby on Rails from the command prompt in Windows 2008 Server running IIS 7.  It has been installed from the Web Platform Installer.

This is a RubyInstaller app from Helicon Zoo.  I believe it runs through FastCGI and IIS.  It's Ruby 1.8.  So I have a C:\Ruby18\ directory.  I can run rails script/server, etc.. but I don't know how to do a restart of the app Windows and IIS.  I've reset IIS and recycled the app pool, but this doesn't seem to effect the app.

Comment: Ruby is a programming language and Rails is a framework, there is no restarting.
You probably want to restart a application written in Ruby on Rails, the procedure for this is different for every environment. You should find out which one the Application is using. For example Passenger with Apache or Passenger with Nginx

Comment: Fair enough, although my question did refer to Rails server.  I'm obviously aware that Ruby is a language.  I'll find out what it's running.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to figure it out. LOL  I am brand spankin' new to Ruby.  I installed it through Helicon Zoo via Web Platform Installer.  It did not install Apache.  It's running under IIS.  I can't find Mongrel or Passenger or any services running.  I don't see anything except a C:\Ruby18 directory.  I don't see Passenger or anything of that nature.  I've tried restarting webRICK from the Ruby command line and still nothing.  There doesn't seem to be a scripts/server found anywhere.  Blah!  I suck at this lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restart Ruby on Rails installed with Helicon Zoo you need to restart IIS Application pool running this Ruby application. This can be achieved by several means:
1. Use IIS Manager to start and stop appropriate application.
2. Type iisreset in the command line. This will restart whole IIS on the server.
3. Add something essential to the web.config file (not spaces), this will also recicle IIS application.
4. Use iisapp command as described [here](http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/3422).
5. Use taskkill command to restart appropriate w3wp.exe process running your application.